# How do I stop water from getting into floor vent?

Tags: bathroom, vent

We have a heating vent located on the floor close to a shower. Occasionally when the floor gets wet it can act like a drain and it causes issues on the ceiling of the floor below.
I could use caulk to permanently seal the vent cover to the floor but I don’t want to do something permanent like that.
What are some other options?[image: vent cover in bathroom]

Comment: Does the water leak into the airduct, or around it ?

Comment: Why do you deem silicone permanent? If under the register, you can still scrape it away at a later time, cutting under the register with a utility knife.

Comment: Do you plan any renovations here?  Could be a good idea to bring the register up into the wall and have it vent out just above the skirting board, leaving the floor to be a floor.

Comment: If you only seal the edge, silicone is not super hard to remove.  Once it cures it's no longer adhesive so if you have skilled hands, you could remove the grate, put down a well planned bead of silicon in a ring so the furnace grate sits on it once it's cured.  If you can get a level top it will seal, and if you don't, it will be a dam at least to the height of the bead.

Comment: I like those ideas. I’m going to use silicone. At least temporarily. Btw, the way the water was getting under the vent it happened to be getting around the air duct (not in it).

Comment: Wait... that's not a drain?

Comment: In what parallel universe was this acceptable? It is certainly not to code in any country I know of.

Comment: @GWarner You know, you may be right, but that doesn't help me.

Comment: Okay true, but I see you already got a good answer and accepted it. So I really was just jokingly curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would first try to prevent that much water from getting out of the tub / shower.
As a back up possibly a 1/8” bead of silicone around the perimeter of the register.  Even tile floors can rot out the framing members that support the floor so preventing the water from getting out would be my first priority.

Comment: Siliconing the register may really be all that's needed, without the bead. I have the identical issue, and a combination of prevention and silicone is sufficient even when the splashiest young one takes a shower.

Answer (score 13):

A splash guard at the corner of the tub may be enough:

[image]

(image from Google)

They're inexpensive, and easy to install.

Answer (score 3):

Don't caulk it, that's just adding to the problem. Caulk is messy, and in this kind of higher traffic area it's not going to last very long, so it's only a matter of time (probably very little time) before the water finds a way around it. The *best* way to fix this is to move the floor register up into the wall where it belongs, but doing that would be pretty involved and probably more hassle than you want to deal with.

Instead of caulk, I would get some silicone gasket material and use that to create a seal between the register and the tile. It might take some searching, but you should be able to find some that is the right thickness (maybe 1/8" or 1/16" ??) and has a permanent<sup>1</sup> adhesive backing on it. Carefully apply that to the bottom edges of the vent cover and tighten it down enough to compress the gasket. It will be *much* less messy than trying to caulk it, and you'll still be able to remove the vent if needed (like when you drop something valuable down there).

---

<sup>1: make sure it is labeled as *permanent*, and follow the directions to prepare the surfaces. I have some permanent Velcro on my kitchen floor that's been there for years, and it's not going anywhere too soon...</sup>

Comment: That makes sense. For the short term I’ve made a sort of gasket with what was on hand, plumber’s putty

Comment: if you have a problem with water entering through the vent grate, you might consider replacing it with one that sits a bit higher (but that's going to stub a lot of toes).

Comment: :-) I see what you’re saying but the water seeps along the grout lines and under the grate.

Answer (score 2):

Put a towel over the vent while you use the shower/bath, then hang it to dry after the water is turned off.  Kind of a pain but it beats the alternative.

Terrible design, but that's nothing new for home construction.  There is always a reason why things are the way they are, but it is usually not a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

Make a bath mat that surrounds the register. Use two hand towels for the long sides and two washcloths (face cloths) for the short sides and sew this into a bath mat with a hole in the center.

Or cut a hole in a small to medium towel or a bath mat.

Answer (score 2):

To stop direct intrusion (not just side seeping) you can buy magnetic register diverters that are clear. They would sit on top of the vent and you could direct them at the wall, where it would deflect any water dripped straight down.

As to side seeping, if you're looking to avoid caulk you can buy closed-cell foam weatherstripping (find a thin variety). Not the greatest over time (water will erode the adhesive) but easily reapplied and you can still remove the vent as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bath mat that surrounds the register. Use two hand towels for the long sides and two washcloths (face cloths) for the short sides and sew this into a bath mat with a hole in the center.

Or cut a hole in a small to medium towel or a bath mat.

Or just lay a hand towel next to and between the register and the tub.

Comment: accidental dupe post of https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/222516/44550 ?